# Background Backup App for Mac to SFTP Server

Tags: mac, backup, sftp, cloud

I am looking an app for my Mac that can backup in the background (such as Backblaze or CrashPlan) that will backup over SFTP, rsync, or scp (I'm using DreamHost's 50GB of personal backups).  Preferably this application would be free, but I would be willing to pay a bit of money.

UPDATE: It would be nice if it could encrypt the backups before sending them as well.

Comment: You do realize that FTP and SFTP are not really related? Do you mean FTPS maybe?

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, I realize that.  I do mean SFTP, which is File Transfer over SSH.